# Android OAuth authentication with YouTube - how to choose my other channel

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm trying to add authentication to my android app for accessing the youtube api - but specifically for managing my other youtube channel.

When I go to YouTube in my desktop browser, I login with my gmail account and my account has two channels - A and B. B is my 'brand account'/channel if that matters.

When I add OAuth (android) to my application, the app shows a box with the google accounts on my device and I click it and choose allow - it automatically logs me into a specific channel (A) with no visible way to "pick" which one I want (B) to authenticate against.

The OAuth guide I followed is here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

I've tried a mobile streaming app from 'streamlabs' (on the play store) and their auth mechanism DOES allow me to choose a particular channel when authenticating - but I dont believe they are performing authentication in the same fashion as I have tried.

[streamlabs screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eP7w.png)
[streamlabs screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLUq7.png)

This link suggests a possible direction [Access YouTube brand account using GoogleSignInApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040198/access-youtube-brand-account-using-googlesigninapi). I, additionally tried following that demo https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android and I can sign in and get an auth token but assuming for channel A as opposed to my brand account on channel B - since it does not ask what channel I am interested in.

In short, I am looking for a way to auth to YouTube and allow me to pick a particular channel (of my own) such that I can create a LiveBroadcast on my B channel. thank you

Any tips/github sample apps would be extremely helpful.